# Unable to install the Azure Functions Core tools version 3 in windows locally

Tags: azure-functions

Previously, I have the azure functions core tools version 3.

For practice purpose, I have installed azure functions core tool version 2 using this command:

```
npm i -g azure-functions-core-tools@2 --unsafe-perm true
```

Now, I'm trying to install the latest azure functions core tools version 3 but how many times I tried through PowerShell or from the [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools#v3) (downloading and installing the application), its not updating. It's still showing the version 2.x

Below code is what I have tried:

```
PS C:\Users\krishna> func --version
2.7.3188
PS C:\Users\krishna> npm i -g azure-functions-core-tools@3 --unsafe-perm true
C:\Users\krishna\AppData\Roaming\npm\azurefunctions -> C:\Users\krishna\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\lib\main.js
C:\Users\krishna\AppData\Roaming\npm\func -> C:\Users\krishna\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\lib\main.js
C:\Users\krishna\AppData\Roaming\npm\azfun -> C:\Users\krishna\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\lib\main.js

> azure-functions-core-tools@3.0.3904 postinstall C:\Users\krishna\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools
> node lib/install.js

attempting to GET "https://functionscdn.azureedge.net/public/3.0.3904/Azure.Functions.Cli.win-x64.3.0.3904.zip"
[==================] Downloading Azure Functions Core Tools

Telemetry
---------
The Azure Functions Core tools collect usage data in order to help us improve your experience.
The data is anonymous and doesn't include any user specific or personal information. The data is collected by Microsoft.

You can opt-out of telemetry by setting the FUNCTIONS_CORE_TOOLS_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT environment variable to '1' or 'true' using your favorite shell.

+ azure-functions-core-tools@3.0.3904
added 51 packages from 31 contributors in 463.874s
PS C:\Users\krishna> func --version
2.7.3188
PS C:\Users\krishna> func version
2.7.3188
PS C:\Users\krishna>
```

And my node installed version is 14.x.

Could anyone help me here how to install the Azure Functions core tools v3 in windows system (locally)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be due to the node version. When I tried to use the latest node version to 16v and npm of 8v I could able to change my azure function tools version from 2v to 3v or 3v to 2v (i.e.. Interchangeable).

Here is the screenshot for your reference.
[image]

Comment: Thank you @SwethaKandikonda-MT, I'm bit confused about node-npm-functions version compatibility. Now it was cleared my issue with the above solution.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
npm i -g azure-functions-core-tools@3 --unsafe-perm true --force
```